# VSS between 4503-E & 4507+E

Tags: cisco, vss

Is it possible to deploy VSS configuration between Catalyst 4503-E and Catalyst 4507+RE ?

This is what I am trying to do, but at VSL establishment I get the following error messages :

```
*May 26 04:35:16.443: %C4K_REDUNDANCY-6-DUPLEX_MODE: The peer Supervisor has been detected
*May 26 04:35:35.770: %SW_LEVEL-6-RESULT: Operational redundancy mode is UNKNOWN, due to software license-level mismatch at ACTIVE and STANDBY. Software Level on     Active: entservices; on Standby: entservices.
*May 26 04:35:45.785: %ISSU-3-PEER_IMAGE_INCOMPATIBLE: Peer image (cat4500e-UNIVERSALK9-M), version (03.04.03.SG) on peer uid (11) is incompatible
*May 26 04:35:45.785: %ISSU-3-PEER_IMAGE_INCOMPATIBLE: Peer image (cat4500e-UNIVERSALK9-M), version (03.04.03.SG) on peer uid (11) is incompatible
*May 26 04:35:55.194: %C4K_REDUNDANCY-2-IOS_VERSION_CHECK_FAIL: IOS version mismatch. Active supervisor version is 15.1(2)SG3 (cat4500e-UNIVERSALK9-M). Standby supervisor version is 15.1(2)SG3 (cat4500e-UNIVERSALK9-M). Redundancy feature may not work as expected.
*May 26 04:35:55.198: %C4K_REDUNDANCY-6-MODE: ACTIVE supervisor initializing for rpr mode
*May 26 04:35:55.462: %C4K_REDUNDANCY-3-COMMUNICATION: Communication with the peer Supervisor has been established
```

After this error message, the redundancy mode on the VSS Standby goes to RPR instead of SSO and it reloads indefinitely because this redundancy mode is not accepted.

I checked my IOS versions on both chassis & they are the same :

```
ROM: 15.0(1r)SG10
System image file is "bootflash:cat4500e-universalk9.SPA.03.04.03.SG.151-2.SG3.bin
```

I am running license level entservices for both chassis

```
Module Name     Role           Current Level     Reboot Level
--------------------------------------------------------------------
WS-X45-SUP7L-E  Active         entservices       entservices
```

My 2 chassis are also configured with redundancy SSO.

Is there a caveat I am not aware of ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two chassis must have the same number of slots.

Refer to: [Cisco: Configuring VSS - Chassis and Modules](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/lan/catalyst4500/15-1-2/XE_340/configuration/guide/config/vss.html#wp1053946)

Comment: Indeed Adam, I just found this also. But I think that with IOS XE 03.05.02 SG and ulterior, I can achieve with asymmetric chassis : http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/lan/catalyst4500/XE3-5-0E/15-21E/configuration/guide/config/vss.html#37306 I am testing this and will update accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

In fact I found out it is possible with IOS XE > 03.05.00 SG. This was not possible before, on IOS XE train 03.04.xx SG

I have tried myself with IOS XE 03.05.02 SG and did not encounter any issues with a 4503-E on one side and a 4507+RE on the other side, the two of them having Sup7-LE.

There is reference on this [here](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/lan/catalyst4500/XE3-5-0E/15-21E/configuration/guide/config/vss.html#37306)

Answer (score 0):

Based on Documents After IOS XE release 3.5.0E Asymmetric mixed chassis Are Supported with 4500-E